# Core Data: does delete an entity remove all relationships of other entities to it?

Tags: core-data, relationship

Say if I have two entities: MySubscription and AllSubscription, MySubscription has a one to one relationship to AllSubscription, thus AllSubscription has a inverse relationship to MySubscription, say:

```
MySub     AllSubs
a   <--->   A
            B
c   <--->   C
            D
e   <--->   E
```

if I delete a, does Core Data automatically set A.mysub to nil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All depends on your choice of delete rule, which can be specified for each relationship. The rule you are describing is called "nullify".